# Is there a limit to regex for javascript pattern searches?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is as simplified as I can get my problem to reproduce.  I get the same result in Safari and Chrome...

```js
var temp = 'a b s40 x';
var div = $('#test');
div.append('<br>' + temp)

var problem = temp.replace(/(^| )(a|c|s\d{1,3}|x)( |$)/g, ' ').trim();
div.append('<br>' + problem); //=b x

var solution = temp.replace(/(^| )(a|c|s\d{1,3})( |$)/g, ' ').replace(/(^| )x( |$)/g, ' ').trim();
div.append('<br>' + solution); //=b
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Hello...
</div>
```

problem uses: `(a|c|s\d{1,3}|x)`

solution uses: `(a|c|s\d{1,3})` and a second replace to get the `x...`

why is solution != problem??

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zo5caun2/

Comment: in solution you additionally chain another .replace(/(^| )x( |$)/g,' ') which capture x and replace it with space. So if you remove second replace then solution is equal to problem. 
I don't get your question.

Comment: @robert in the 'problem'  there is a '|x' that is not in the 'solution'..  in the solution the '|x' was removed and moved to the second replace.

Comment: FYI: You can use `\b` to match word boundaries rather than `(^| )` and `( |$)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it won't replace overlapping matches. When it matches `s40`, the match includes the spaces before and after the word. It can't match `x` because there's no space before it, since that was part of the previous match. And it's not at the beginning, so `^` doesn't match before it, either.

That doesn't happen in `solution` because you're doing two separate replacements, so the second replace doesn't care what was matched in the first one.

Use `\b` to match word boundaries instead of explicit spaces.

```js
var temp = 'a b s40 x';
var div = $('#test');
div.append('<br>' + temp)

var problem = temp.replace(/\b(a|c|s\d{1,3}|x)\b/g, ' ').trim();
div.append('<br>' + problem); //=b x

var solution = temp.replace(/\b(a|c|s\d{1,3})\b/g, ' ').replace(/\bx\b/g, ' ').trim();
div.append('<br>' + solution); //=b
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test'>Hello...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need modify first regex to have the same result as in the second regex this should solve your problem.

i'm not sure why you put this (^| ) - start or space and space or end( |$). you can use \b

If you need ensure that are some chars in front or after capture then you can use look behind.

```js
var temp = 'a b s40 x';

var problem = temp.replace(/\b(a|c|s\d{1,3}|x)\b/g,' ').trim();
console.log(problem)

var solution = temp.replace(/(^| )(a|c|s\d{1,3})( |$)/g,' ').replace(/(^| )x( |$)/g,' ').trim();
console.log(solution)
```